# Линия SVG наполовину сплошная, наполовину пунктирная

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

У меня есть встроенный объект SVG и несколько строк в нем. Я пытаюсь закрасить половину линии сплошной, а другую половину пунктирной.

```html
<svg height="30" width="300">
  <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="4">
    <line stroke-dasharray="50%,1%,1%,1%" x1="10" x2="280" y1="10" y2="10" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Svg line half solid, half dashed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67686823/7394871) от участника  [@YSFKBDY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6166703/ysfkbdy).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/67686823/7394871

Answer (score 1):

- Поместите в line `pathLength = "100"`, чтобы общая длина
  рассчитывалась как 100 единиц (100 units).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength

- установите для units `stroke-dasharray` нужный pattern:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<svg>
    <line pathLength="100" stroke-dasharray="50,2,5,2,5,2,5,2,5,2,5,2,5" 
          stroke="black" stroke-width="4"
          x1="10" x2="280" y1="10" y2="10" />
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67686926/7394871) от участника  [@Danny'365CSI'Engelman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2520800/danny-365csi-engelman) .</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Самым простым было бы использование двухстрочных объектов. Один для сплошной линии, а другой для пунктирной. Вот пример:

```html
<svg height="30" width="300">
  <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="4">
    <line x1="10" x2="150" y1="10" y2="10" />
    <line stroke-dasharray="5,5" x1="150" x2="280" y1="10" y2="10" />    
  </g>
</svg>
```

Свойство [stroke-dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) будет повторяться бесконечно, поэтому, если "шаблон", который вы вводите, не длится до конца строки, он снова будет использовать первое значение и повторять шаблон.
Вы можете видеть, что в вашем примере длинное тире (значение 50%) повторяется 3 раза с 3 маленькими черточками (значения 1%) между ними (2 пустых и одно сплошное).

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67686895/7394871) от участника  [@web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki).</sub>